# How to specify request body in Spring boot for swagger UI?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have the following annotated controller for swagger:

```
  @PostMapping("/getMediaDataProduct/V2")
    @ResponseBody
    @ApiOperation(value = "get media data product v2")
    @ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful", response = MediaDataProductResponseV2.class)})

    @ApiImplicitParams(value = {
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "xxxxx", value = "xxxx", paramType = "header", required = true),
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "xxxx", value = "xxxx", paramType = "header", required = true),
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "xxxx", value = "xxxx", paramType = "header"),
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "xxxx", value = "xxxx", paramType = "header", required = true),
            //  @ApiImplicitParam(name = "xxxxxx", value = "xxx", paramType = "header" ,required = true),
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "xxxxxx", value = "xxxxx", paramType = "header"),
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "xxxxxxx", value = "xxxxxxxx", paramType = "header", required = true)})

    public ResponseEntity getMediaDataProductV2(@RequestBody final String request, @RequestHeader final HttpHeaders headers) {
        Slogger.get().debug("/getMediaDataProduct/V2: this.mediaDataService: " + this.mediaDataService);

        MediaDataProductResponseV2 response = mediaDataService.getMediaDataProductV2(request);
        HttpStatus status = getHttpStatus(response.getStatusMessages(), response.getSystemErrors());
        List<StatusMessage> statusMessages = appendSuccessStatusMessage(response.getStatusMessages(), status);
        if(statusMessages !=null) {
            response.setStatusMessages(statusMessages);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, new HttpHeaders(), status);
    }
```

How can you specify the request body so it's displayed in the swagger UI?

update: I have tried to research on this in many forums but doesn't seem to find an answer. "How can you specify the request body class by using swagger annotations just as I do with ApiResponses?". There is a default parameter in swagger UI created for body but don't know how to specify it by referencing the request body class.

Comment: Please share your observations first. There are a lot of blogs and forums explaining swagger documentation. Mention What exactly is wrong in your setup?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you need to have a response type shown in the swagger definition. Most of the time Swagger will automatically map your method return type as response type.

But, it fails to do so when it's a generic class, as in your case its `ResponseEntity`.
If you can make your return type to something like `ResponseEntity<MediaDataProductResponseV2>`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Swagger documentation](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiImplicitParam.html#paramType()), you can declare paramType attribute at @ApiImplicitParam only with the following values:

> Valid values are path, query, body, header or form.

> the Default is ""

In your case, try to do something like this.

```
@ApiImplicitParams(value = {
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "request", value = "The body is a simple string", paramType = "body", required = true),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "headers", value = "It'll contain all header attributes in request", paramType = "header", required = true)})
public ResponseEntity getMediaDataProductV2(@RequestBody final String request, @RequestHeader final HttpHeaders headers) {
    Slogger.get().debug("/getMediaDataProduct/V2: this.mediaDataService: " + this.mediaDataService);
```